# Show that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac n{n^2+k^2}=\frac \pi 4$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

My Work:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac n{n^2+k^2}$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{n^2+k^2}$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n(\frac1{n^2+1^2}+\frac1{n^2+2^2}+\frac1{n^2+3^2}+...+\frac1{n^2+(n-1)^2}+\frac1{2n^2})$$

I'm not really sure where to proceed from here, or if this even is the correct direction that I should take this problem. My math Analysis class has covered up to Riemannian integrals, but I'm not sure that they will be entirely helpful in this instance.

Comment: hint: pull out the $n^2$ in the denominator and use the definition of the riemann integral.\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k\to1}^{n}\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k\to1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+(\frac{k}{n})^2}\frac{1}{n}$$
$$=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$
$$=\tan^{-1}(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k^2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}$$

So $$ \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2+k^2} = \int\limits_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx = \arctan(1) - \arctan(0) = \frac{\pi}{4}$$